# Randomizing Instances of Object in List Error CS1503 in C#

Tags: c#, oop, console-application

I am creating a console app in c#. The apps purpose is to create robots, randomly assign 5 tasks once the robot is created, then display the robots total time etc. I have a class for BotTask and for Robot.

Having trouble with the following:
I am initializing each individual BotTask then attempting to load them into a list, to randomize them and return 5 BotTask's that can be assigned to a Robot.

I was thinking if each BotTask has an index property: I can randomize an integer then use that index property to select which BotTask is called by random.

When I try this I am receiving error code CS1503 (Arguement 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'BotOMat.BotTask') and am unsure if I am trying to complete this process the correct way.

Here is the code I have written for the BotTask class:

```
public class BotTask
{


    //initialize bot tasks
    public static readonly BotTask DISHES = new BotTask("Dishes", "Do the dishes", 1000, 1);
    public static readonly BotTask SWEEP = new BotTask("Sweep", "Sweep the house", 3000, 2);
    public static readonly BotTask LAUNDRY = new BotTask("Laundry", "Do the laundry", 10000, 3);
    public static readonly BotTask RECYCLING = new BotTask("Recycling", "Take out the recycling", 4000, 4);
    public static readonly BotTask SAMMICH = new BotTask("Sammich", "Make a sammich", 7000, 5);
    public static readonly BotTask LAWN = new BotTask("Lawn", "Mow the lawn", 20000, 6);
    public static readonly BotTask RAKE = new BotTask("Rake", "Rake the leaves", 18000, 7);
    public static readonly BotTask BATH = new BotTask("Bath", "Give the dog a bath", 14500, 8);
    public static readonly BotTask BAKE = new BotTask("Bake", "Bake some cookies", 8000, 9);
    public static readonly BotTask WASH = new BotTask("Wash", "Wash the car", 20000, 10);


    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public int Duration { get; private set; }
    public int Index { get; private set; }


    private BotTask(string name, string description, int duration, int index)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Duration = duration;
        Index = index;
    }

    public static List<BotTask> randomizeBotTasks()
    {
        var loadBotTasks = new List<BotTask> { DISHES, SWEEP, LAUNDRY, RECYCLING, SAMMICH, LAWN, RAKE, BATH, BAKE, WASH };


        int i = 1;
        List<BotTask> randomizedBotTasks = new List<BotTask>();
        while (i <= 5)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            int index = random.Next(loadBotTasks.Count);
            randomizedBotTasks.Add(index);
            i++;
        }
        return randomizedBotTasks;
    }
```

Without intentionally adding a second question here I would like to return this list of BotTasks to my Robot Class. So after user creates a Robot, 5 randomized BotTasks will be assigned to it.

Here is how I am trying to achieve this in my Robot class:

```
    public class Robot
{

    public string BotName { get; set; }

    public RobotType BotType { get; set; }
    public string BotTypeDescription => BotType.GetDescription();

    public TimeSpan TimeElapsed { get; set; }

    private readonly List<BotTask> _tasks = new List<BotTask>();

    //public IEnumerable<BotTask> Tasks => _tasks;

    public Robot(string botName, RobotType botType, TimeSpan timeElapsed = default)
    {
        this.BotName = botName;
        this.BotType = botType;
        TimeElapsed = timeElapsed;
    }

        public static void CreateRobot()
    {

        var robotsList = new List<Robot>();
        //loop until there are no more robots
        while (true)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter robot name: ");
            var robotName = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(robotName))
            {
                break;  //empty robot, time to list things out
            }

            //RobotType? robotType = null;

            RobotType? robotType = null;
            while (!robotType.HasValue)
            {
                robotType = GetResponseUsingEnum<RobotType>("Robots");
            }

            var robot = new Robot(robotName, robotType.Value);
            robotsList.Add(robot);

        }

        //At this point, we have a fully populated list of robots, each with some tasks
        foreach (var robot in robotsList)
        {
            robot.Show();
        }
    }

    public static T? GetResponseUsingEnum<T>(string prompt) where T : struct, Enum
    {
        //Loop until a good answer (or no answer)
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{prompt}: Please enter one of:");
            var values = (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
            foreach (var enumValue in values)
            {
                var description = enumValue.GetDescription<T>();
                var intValue = Convert.ToInt32(enumValue);
                Console.WriteLine($"{intValue}: {description}");
            }
            Console.Write(">> ");
            var response = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
            {
                return (T?)null;
            }
            if (Enum.TryParse<T>(response, out var val))
            {
                if (values.Contains(val))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"You answered: {val}");
                    return val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Appreciate any help in advance - thank you.

Comment: You are adding an int, index to the list. Not a task.

Comment: Side note: don't create a new `Random` inside of a loop. Use a static field/property  to hold a single value

Answer (score 0):

You can't add integer value to `List<BotTask>`
Use this:

```
  public static List<BotTask> randomizeBotTasks()
    {
        var loadBotTasks = new List<BotTask> { DISHES, SWEEP, LAUNDRY, RECYCLING, SAMMICH, LAWN, RAKE, BATH, BAKE, WASH };


        int i = 1;
        List<BotTask> randomizedBotTasks = new List<BotTask>();
        while (i <= 5)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            int index = random.Next(loadBotTasks.Count);
            randomizedBotTasks.Add(loadBotTasks[index]);
            i++;
        }
        return randomizedBotTasks;
    }
```